# How to simply create a folder with a task on TFS 2017 build definition?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I'm able to do that with powershell, but I'd like to use a simple task instead. Is it possible? I couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, there is no build-in task/extension in TFS/VSTS [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=folder&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) for now.

You have to either **customize yourself**, or simply add a single-line script such as with using *mkdir*`

`if not exist "$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\(foldername)" mkdir "$(TF_BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY)\(foldername)"`

Comment: Thanks, I had to confirm it, though it seems weird to me that a common and simple operation like creating a folder is not implemented already as a task.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You could simply add a [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/powershell?view=vsts) task to add the powershell path or add inline script.

[image]

In addition, you could [develop your own build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts) to create a folder.

Comment: Thanks, but I said that I'm already able to do that using PowerShell, but I'm looking for a way to use an existing task or an extention.

Comment: It seems like an awful lot of additional hoops to jump through for something that can be done in a single-line script.